# how to pass a scope variable inside ng-repeat to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a repeat loop in my html, and I need to pass a variable that is displayed in a table row to an javascript array. I've seen other similar answers but nothing seems to work.

```html
<tbody id="search-results-body">
  <tr ng-repeat="result in filteredResults ">
    <td id = "latitude" ><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.latitude}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.longitude}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.name}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.address}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.phone}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.serviceType.name}}</a></td>
                  
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to get all the {{result.latitude}} values and put them in an array

Can someone please advise me of a way to do this??
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand where're you trying to pass a scope. What doesn't work?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. The view only displays what is in the data model and what you need is in that data model. Not at all clear what you are wanting to do other than that

Answer (score 0):

In Html you use something like this

```
<tbody id="search-results-body">
  <tr ng-repeat="result in filteredResults " ng-init="newLongitudeArray[$index]=result.longitude">
    <td id = "latitude" ><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.latitude}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.longitude}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.name}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.address}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.phone}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="#/Services/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.serviceType.name}}</a></td>

   </tr>
</tbody>
```

or in Your javascript you use something like this.

```
var newArray = [];
filteredResults.forEach(function(item){
newArray.push(item.longitude);
})
```